# Getting X-Mailer attribute in php imap

Tags: php, imap

how I can get X-Mailer attribute in php imap lib ?

I can't find any fetch function for attribute  http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchheader.php

```
 $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

  $header =  imap_fetchheader($inbox, 1);
  var_dump($header);


/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

output I am getting is

```
 string(405) "MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.42.228.195; Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:06 -0800 (PST)
Date: Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:06 -0800
Message-ID: <AANLkTikj8NgGgkG=Of=V6VvNSt2QZ3WLNKUVZxpcs4tk@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Get Gmail on your mobile phone
From: Gmail Team <mail-noreply@google.com>
To: test case2 <email@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf302234f1c34163049c73853c

"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method:**

- Fetch headers with imap_fetchheader()
- Extract X-Mailer field from headers
- Extract value from field

**Example:**

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
if (!$inbox) {
    echo('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
    exit;
}
$header_string =  imap_fetchheader($inbox, 1);
preg_match_all('/([^: ]+): (.+?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m', 
        $header_string, $matches);
$headers = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
$xmailer = $headers['X-Mailer'];
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: In your example the mail does not have the X-Mailer header field.

Comment: @Vivek, I added an example, I've tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Peter but what about these parameter I can't see these (http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/)  custom header supported by google

Comment: @Vivek, I have no clue, but that's another question, for someone else, as it states 'assumes familiarity with the IMAP protocol', which I don't have.

Comment: @Peter ok thanks, So there is not way to retrieve those attributes ?

Comment: @Vivek, Those are extensions, not header fields.

Comment: @Peter ok thanks for your help.
This extensions world is new for me :). I don't have any idea about them . 
I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632199/how-to-retrieve-gmail-imap-extension-in-php

Comment: The regexp is not realy OK because a header car directly have a new line after double-dot (:). Use this instead preg_match_all('/([^:\s]+): (.*?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m', $header_string, $matches);

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The following uses code from other, but I am sure it would help others (in my case I needed this because [ddeboer/imap](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap) library does not support headers).

[Peter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5631445/1048171) is great but I had to use [fred727's regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631086/getting-x-mailer-attribute-in-php-imap#comment61912182_5631445) to avoid getting keys with newline characters.

Because an e-mail can have a given header multiple times, I had to use [an `array_combine()` variant](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-combine.php#118397) that allows duplicate keys.

Here is the final code to parse a RFC822 headers-part string (fetching such part is out of scope):

```
function parse_rfc822_headers(string $header_string): array {
    // Reference:
    // * Base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631086/getting-x-mailer-attribute-in-php-imap/5631445#5631445
    // * Improved regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631086/getting-x-mailer-attribute-in-php-imap#comment61912182_5631445
    preg_match_all(
        '/([^:\s]+): (.*?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m',
        $header_string,
        $matches
    );
    $headers = array_combine_groupkeys($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    return $headers;
}

function array_combine_groupkeys(array $keys, array $values): array {
    // Reference: "welcome at el hyphen mustafa" on 2015-11-29 09:46 (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-combine.php#118397)
    $result = [];
    foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
        $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
    }
    array_walk(
        $result, 
        function (&$v) {
            $v = (count($v) === 1) ? array_pop($v): $v;
        }
    );
    return $result;
}
```

Which works great. Here is an example using the same `$string` (with added `Received` header):

```
const RFC2822_EOL = "\r\n";

$string = 
'MIME-Version: 1.0' . RFC2822_EOL .
'Received: by 10.42.228.195; Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:09 -0800 (PST)' . RFC2822_EOL .
'Received: by 127.0.0.1; Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:06 -0800 (PST)' . RFC2822_EOL .
'Date: Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:06 -0800' . RFC2822_EOL .
'Message-ID: <AANLkTikj8NgGgkG=Of=V6VvNSt2QZ3WLNKUVZxpcs4tk@mail.gmail.com>' . RFC2822_EOL .
'Subject: Get Gmail on your mobile phone' . RFC2822_EOL .
'From: Gmail Team <mail-noreply@google.com>' . RFC2822_EOL .
'To: test case2 <email@gmail.com>' . RFC2822_EOL .
'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf302234f1c34163049c73853c' . RFC2822_EOL .
'' . RFC2822_EOL;

var_dump(parse_rfc822_headers($string));
```

Which outputs:

```
array(8) {
  ["MIME-Version"]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["Received"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(55) "by 10.42.228.195; Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:09 -0800 (PST)"
    [1]=>
    string(51) "by 127.0.0.1; Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:06 -0800 (PST)"
  }
  ["Date"]=>
  string(31) "Wed, 16 Feb 2011 21:18:06 -0800"
  ["Message-ID"]=>
  string(62) "<AANLkTikj8NgGgkG=Of=V6VvNSt2QZ3WLNKUVZxpcs4tk@mail.gmail.com>"
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(30) "Get Gmail on your mobile phone"
  ["From"]=>
  string(36) "Gmail Team <mail-noreply@google.com>"
  ["To"]=>
  string(28) "test case2 <email@gmail.com>"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(60) "multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf302234f1c34163049c73853c"
}
```